# Is it possible to have a Leaflet control with large images / icons

Tags: leaflet

Im trying to create a map where the layer control have large icons or images, and the "buttons" are located in the bottom of the map and not on the sides. I have used the simple controls until now.

I want something similar to this, where the control is located in along the bottom and not in the side.

https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Does anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started. Basically you can add any HTML inside the layer control layer names.

`var basemaps = {
      "<div class='layers-control-img'><img src='assets/images/layer-control-images/osm-streets.png'></div> Streets": osm
    };`

Then part of the CSS:

`.layers-control-img {
    max-width: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

You can see it in action at http://ovrdc.github.io/parcel-viewer/

Comment: is there any way to make that variable. E.g make the text `<total> markers`, where `<total>` is a variable? Thus `5 markers`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code for the `leaflet-providers` preview](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers/blob/master/preview/index.html), you'll see that it uses [Leaflet.Control.Minimap](https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap).

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5826 download images from the link and keep in the folder structure